# Google Tracking Issue

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a newsletter form on my website which is getting track on every hit of submit button. But now I recognize that if I simply hit submit button without filling any email than also it get track by GA code.
I want my newsletter form should only be tracked on successful submission and not on any blank submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind your event tracking to a **successful form submission**.  It sounds like you are currently binding it to the click event on the submit button.

Start by getting your tracking event bound to submit event of the form (and not click event of the button) and then you'll have to write some code to find out when the form submission is valid.

Without further information about you page construction no-one can help any more than this.